# how to sort json data in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my Json data:

```
call_record: [
{
"machine_location":"Restaurant",
"allocation_date:"2008-08-31"
"status":"C",
"customer_address":"pune"
}
{
"machine_location":"Restaurant",
"allocation_date:"2008-08-31"
"status":"N",
"customer_address":"pune"
}
{
"machine_location":"Restaurant",
"allocation_date:"2008-08-31"
"status":"O",
"customer_address":"pune"
}]
```

In my app i want to show data in listview whose date is allocation_date=2008-08-31
Here is my code for display data in ListView:

```
    Widget todayCall(BuildContext context,resultCheck3){
          return Container(
           child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child:Text("Today's Calls"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                    FutureBuilder(
                      future: api3,
                     builder: (context,snapshot){
                     if (snapshot.data != null) {
                      return Container(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext conxt, int index) {
                      return Card(
                      child: Padding(
                      child: ExpansionTile(
                      title: Text('${snapshot.data[index]['customer_name']}') 
                      subtitle: Text('${snapshot.data[index]   ['error_message']}'"\n"'${snapshot.data[index]['allocation_date']}'
                              trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down,size: 30.0,
                              children: <Widget>[
                              ListTile(
                              title: Text("Machine Model",style: TextStyle(fontSize:13)),
                              subtitle: Text('${snapshot.data[index]['machine_type']}')
                              ),
                              ListTile(
                              title: Text("Location",style: TextStyle(fontSize:13)),
                              subtitle: Text('${snapshot.data[index]['location_address']}')
                              ),
])))
}))
}}))])
```

I called this method in Body():

```
 body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              callSummary(context,resultCheck2),
              todayCall(context,resultCheck3),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

[now in my output all data in list view ][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3VIz.png .show data whose allocation_date is 2008-08-31

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a filter icon above the listview, so you can use the date picker to select the date and based on the date you can filter the list and show it in your list view.

let me know if this works for you.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Before returning a widget in the future builder, you can check if the date condition is satisfied.

```
if (snapshot.data != null) {
                      return Container(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext conxt, int index) {
                      if(snapshot.data[index]['allocation_date'] == '2008-08-31'){
                        return Card(.....
                        .
                        .
                        .
                      else{
                        return Container(height: 0); //return a container with zero height in the else case because you cant return a null and your return must be a widget
                      }
                        .
                        .
                        .
```